# ADCS WebEnrollment : The context was acquired as silent

Tags: active-directory, certificate, certificate-authority, web-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have setup Active Directory Certificate Services with Web Enrollment and I have the following error when enrolling certificate on other computers that are in the same domain :

> Certificate enrollment for Local system failed in authentication to
>   all urls for enrollment server associated with policy id:
>   {4C83C22A-975D-4B74-8300-B61D978FF2C2} (Provider could not perform the
>   action since the context was acquired as silent. 0x80090022
>   (-2146893790 NTE_SILENT_CONTEXT)). Failed to enroll for template:
>   MyCertificateTemplate

Users can enroll certificates with their account on my computer but not on other computers even if their computers are in the same domain. ADCS & Web Enrollment service are on a remote server.

Why? How can an acquired a context without being in silent?

Answer (score -1):

I have same situation for Windows 7 clients. I dont have this patch yet. But maybe this link will help you.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2633205